# React native 0.71.0 init is not working in new project

Tags: react-native, version, init, npx

I try to follow up React Native document [setup environment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?platform=ios) but I met an error

```
PS Nghia:\development> npx react-native init F3tProvider --version 0.71.0
error Failed to load configuration of your project.
```

Can anyone solve this? Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the installed react-native

```
npm uninstall -g react-native
```

or

```
npm uninstall react-native
```

then try it again

```
npx react-native init F3tProvider --version 0.71.0
```

Comment: I tried but still not working

Comment: Can you please share which node version and npm version you are using?

Comment: I'm using  Node v16.14.0 and npm is 9.7.2